# how to Select top 1 value from this result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query in a stored procedure:

```
SELECT    DISTINCT
 a.UserProfileId,
 a.FromProfileId,
  mm.FromProfileId as ToProfileID
FROM      ( SELECT
          mup.UserProfileId,
          mmb.FromProfileId
        FROM      dbo.Mindcracker_MailBox mmb
        LEFT JOIN Mindcracker_UserProfile mup
          ON mmb.ToProfileId=mup.UserProfileId
        WHERE     mup.UserProfileId=1144 ) a
LEFT JOIN  dbo.Mindcracker_MailBox mm
ON a.FromProfileId=mm.ToProfileId
```

The above query produces the result below:

```
UserProfielId  FromProfileID  ToProfielID
1144    1152    1144
1144    1152    1378
1144    1152    1483
1144    1333    1143
1144    1333    1148
1144    1333    1290
1144    1333    1297
1144    1333    1333
1144    1333    1378
1144    1378    1143
1144    1378    1185
1144    1378    1333
1144    1378    1378
1144    1483    1143
1144    1483    1144
1144    1483    1297
1144    1483    1483
1144    11526   1148
1144    11526   1290
1144    11526   1333
1144    11526   1378
1144    11526   11526
```

I want to get only the top value on the basis FromProfileId Column and my output should be this:

```
1144    1152    1144
1144    1333    1143
1144    1378    1143
1144    1483    1143
```

Comment: i think you need to use `GROUP BY` FromProfileID

Comment: do u want to get top 4 records only?

Comment: Sounds like you want to get the first ToProfileID for each FromProfileID... except for some reason you don't want/expect the 1144, 11526, 1148 row? Also which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What does "It is not working.." mean ?

Answer (score 0):

try this query to get top 4 value as you OutPut.

Execute this Query After you will receive the result from stored procedure:

> SELECT TOP 4 FromProfielId , UserProfielId, ToProfielID FROM [Your TableName];

I hope you will get your solution.

Comment: Sorry, not working top 4 here. it only gives top 4 values. But i need top 1 on the basis of FromProfileID.

Comment: Refer this link.
and keep as same it is..
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove distinct and add group by UserProfileId, FromProfileId

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
ORDER BY amount [ColumnName] LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

execute below query on the result set you got from stored procedure.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [TableName] ORDER BY FromProfielId;
```

Answer (score 0):

`try using ranking_functions`      [tutorial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

```
 with cte as (
        SELECT    DISTINCT
         a.UserProfileId,
         a.FromProfileId,
          mm.FromProfileId as ToProfileID
        FROM      ( SELECT
                  mup.UserProfileId,dense_rank() over (order by mmb.FromProfileid) as rn

                FROM      dbo.Mindcracker_MailBox mmb
                LEFT JOIN Mindcracker_UserProfile mup
                  ON mmb.ToProfileId=mup.UserProfileId
                WHERE     mup.UserProfileId=1144 ) a
        LEFT JOIN  dbo.Mindcracker_MailBox mm
        ON a.FromProfileId=mm.ToProfileId
        order by profile_ID
        )

        select * from cte where rn between 1 AND 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is for a long time ago, but probably someone can find it useful.

To get the first row of each data set, you need to window your result set using window functions.

I just make your result set and query the output based on that. It can be expanded to the original query.

**Create table**

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl(UserProfielId INT, FromProfileID INT, ToProfielID INT)
```

**Sample data**

```
INSERT #tbl
SELECT 1144  ,  1152  ,  1144 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  1152  ,  1378 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  1152  ,  1483 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  1333  ,  1143 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  1333  ,  1148 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  1333  ,  1290 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  1333  ,  1297 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  1333  ,  1333 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  1333  ,  1378 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  1378  ,  1143 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  1378  ,  1185 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  1378  ,  1333 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  1378  ,  1378 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  1483  ,  1143 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  1483  ,  1144 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  1483  ,  1297 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  1483  ,  1483 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  11526 ,  1148 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  11526 ,  1290 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  11526 ,  1333 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  11526 ,  1378 UNION ALL
SELECT 1144  ,  11526 ,  11526
```

**Query**

Use `ROW_NUMBER` function to window your result set in a `CTE` and then make a query based on your main query.

```
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FromProfileID ORDER BY FromProfileID) AS Rn
            ,UserProfielId
            ,FromProfileID
            ,ToProfielID
    FROM #tbl
)

SELECT  UserProfielId
        ,FromProfileID
        ,ToProfielID
FROM C
WHERE Rn = 1
```

**Output**

```
UserProfielId   FromProfileID   ToProfielID
1144            1152            1144
1144            1333            1143
1144            1378            1143
1144            1483            1143
1144            11526           1148
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f336/1)